# Dates Selection on Hover Jquery

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-hover

I want to do following,

1. Dates should be selected on hover.
2. If any date selected within the calendar, on hover i need to apply a class("Selected") from that element on wards.

I did this functionality with the below script.

```
    $("#WBECalBodyNav a").hover(function (e) {
            if ($("#WBECalBodyNav a.WBECheckIn").length != 0) {
                //Step 1: Check for the current element Parent.
                if ($(this).parent().attr("id") == "WBECalRightPane") {
                    //Step 2: Remove all selected classes before Checkin Class
                    $("#WBECalBodyNav").children().eq(1).find("a.WBESelected.WBECheckIn").prevAll().removeClass("WBESelected");
                    //Step 3: Find Checkin Class and remove Chekout class until current element.
                    $("#WBECalBodyNav").children().eq(1).find("a.WBESelected.WBECheckIn").nextUntil($(this)).removeClass("WBECheckOut");
                    //Step 4: Find Checkin Class and add Selected class until current element.
                    $("#WBECalBodyNav").children().eq(1).find("a.WBESelected.WBECheckIn").nextUntil($(this)).addClass("WBESelected");
                    //Step 5:Add Checkout Class for Current element 
                    $(this).addClass("WBESelected WBECheckOut");
                    //Step 6: Remove Selected,Checkout Class for current element next all elements
                    $("#WBECalBodyNav").children().eq(1).find($(this)).nextAll().removeClass("WBESelected WBECheckOut");
                    ////Step 7: Remove Checkout Class for current element next all elements
                    //$("#WBECalBodyNav").children().eq(0).find($(this)).nextAll().removeClass("WBECheckOut");
                }
                else {
                    //Step 2: Remove all selected classes before Checkin Class
                    $("#WBECalBodyNav").children().eq(0).find("a.WBESelected.WBECheckIn").prevAll().removeClass("WBESelected Chekout");
                    //Step 3: Find Checkin Class and remove Chekout class until current element.
                    $("#WBECalBodyNav").children().eq(0).find("a.WBESelected.WBECheckIn").nextUntil($(this)).removeClass("WBECheckOut");
                    //Step 4: Find Checkin Class and add Selected class until current element.
                    $("#WBECalBodyNav").children().eq(0).find("a.WBESelected.WBECheckIn").nextUntil($(this)).addClass("WBESelected");
                    //Step 5:Add Checkout Class for Current element 
                    $(this).addClass("WBESelected WBECheckOut");
                    //Step 6: Remove Selected,Checkout Class for current element next all elements
                    $("#WBECalBodyNav").children().eq(0).find($(this)).nextAll().removeClass("WBESelected WBECheckOut");
                    //Step 7: Remove Checkout Class for current element next all elements
                    //$("#WBECalBodyNav").children().eq(0).find($(this)).nextAll().removeClass("WBECheckOut");
                }
                //Step 8: Return False
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

It is working for individual div elements, but i want this for total 2 div elements.

i.e., if i select any date in first div i should be able to continue my selection on second div.

But, this current script is not working to do this functionality.

Please provide your suggestion.

Comment: Don't give us your requirements, start with these one by one, if any problems occurs then ask after showing the efforts you have made.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am new to post questions, If i am not clear about my problem please let me know.

Comment: I had done the following changes and able to get my required results.